# Mix two models to the same endPoint in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning DRF right now, and I would like to know can I mix two models link by foreign key to one specific endpoint.

For example let say that I have two models:

```
Model1:
class Car(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

Model2:
Class Revision(models.Model):
    revision1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    revision2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    car_is = models.ForeignKey(
    Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

What I would like to achieve would be to get at url: "/car/1" (car datails) the data of the specific car with the Revisions.

I am using Class Based view with DRF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access car's revision by `revision_set` attribute. So you need to add `revision_set` field to the car serializer:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('Name', 'Year', 'revision_set')
        depth = 1
```

Note to get revision details instead of simple id list you can use [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) meta option.